# How to make an Entity read-only or JPA entities immutables?

Tags: ebean

I want avoid updates undue with Ebean, because it happens to Hibernate(@Immutable) and EclipseLink(@ReadOnly).

Comment: With Ebean you'd be best just to not have any setters on the entity bean - why don't you do that?

Comment: It is an alternative. Nice!

Comment: You can also use ... query.setReadOnly(true) on mutable beans but making the bean itself immutable by removing the setters would be a better approach imo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an Entity read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115527/how-to-make-an-entity-read-only)

Answer (score 1):

So as an answer:

Just remove the setter methods and make the bean immutable that way.

Comment: Removing the setter doesn't work with collections. See this other topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115527/how-to-make-an-entity-read-only