# Only Insertable Entity

Tags: jpa

Is there a way **in JPA** to do a Entity **just be insertable**? 
I mean, in any case, not just in a mapped column. In my case I am not allowed to put a trigger in DB. 
If I throw a Exception on PreUpdate. May it works?

**CAN INSERT**

Comment: Do you mean an entity that: a) can not be updated _OR_ b) an entity that can not be updated and can not be read ?

Comment: a) can not be updated.
It can be inserted and read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an Entity read-only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115527/how-to-make-an-entity-read-only)

Comment: No, I want to make the insert. And put the fields protected won't protect the update/insert, reflection can be used. And it is not JPA solution.

Comment: How about annotating fields with `@Column(updatable = false)` ?

Comment: Maybe, can I do that to a not entity column? This way I could annotate all the fields of the entity.