# How to protect columns in hibernate from being read

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, passwords

Lets say I have models Configuration and User.
In Configuration I specify relation to User like this:
       `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name= "user")
private User author;`

And then when I want all configuration per specific user I get something like this:
`{"id":1,"key":"Layout","value":"boxed","author":{"id":1,"name":"Roy","login":"roy","password":"spring"}}`

How can I protect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115527/how-to-make-an-entity-read-only

Comment: _from being read_ is what I dont understand.. I dont know why any one wud do that in Hibernate.. You can handle this at your app,s middleware

Comment: DO you instead what to encrypt the password or remove the entries from your JSON response??Please specify what are you using for Json parsing in that case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution. In entity class, if I join column I can simply put annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties({"prop1", "prop2"}), or if it is standard type property @JsonIgnore is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this solves your problem. But it looks like typical need of View instead of direct table fetch.

In View you can control which all columns to be read or not to be read.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of Hibernate-read protection. You can protect fileds from beeing updated or inserted using declarations (insertable = false, updatable = false).
If you want not to give some fields to the user you should use high-level logic, like filtering fields in your Json.

Comment: Thank you. I found something about lazy fetching type where I could implement that or I should as u said do something before json return in controller.

Comment: @Admir Šabanović Lazy won't work with simple types or OneToOne references if they are marked as nullable. If nullable=false that might do the trick.