# How in hibernate we can add reference of another entity without persisting that entity

Tags: hibernate

There are two tables.
1: RewardTxn
2: RewardTxnType

RewardTxnType is a master table.
I want to reference RewardTxnType during persist of RewardTxn without persisting RewardTxnType entry.

```
Class Fields are like below;

@Entity
Class RewardTxn  {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
int id;

int points;

@OneToOne
RewardTxnType type;

}

@Entity
Class RewardTxnType {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
int id;

int name;

int disc;

int unitPoint; 

}
```

RewardTxnType is already populated i just want add that reference when persisting RewardTxn;

Please let me know what are the options we can use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115527/how-to-make-an-entity-read-only

Comment: @EssexBoy this is not what i want, my RewardTxnType is already populated in DB. Now i want to make it referenced with RewardTxn as there is OneToOne Relationship.

Example: 
RewardTxn rewardTxn = new RewardTxn();
RewardTxnType type = getRewardTxnType(id);
rewardTxn.setRewardTxnType(type);

Now here i need to know which annotation i should use to avoid rewardTxnType entry again in the table.