# Is it necessary to use Entity annotation for Select query records from Database

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have spring boot application with JPA and MySQL. The table is already created and data are present. From the spring boot application, we need to create two API - get a particular record using id and get all the records. I created a model class but confused with usage of `@Entity`. Because I'm not going to insert/delete a record from the database. I want to use only for select the record.

For Select query (`findBy`), do we need to use `@Entity` annotation at the top of model class?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to use `@Entity` to mark your model class, this tells JPA that your class is used for mapping to and from a database table. If you want to make sure that you don't accidentally overwrite the data, you could implement a check via `@EntityListener`, [as described in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32207163/561543)