# Remove selected entites from being updated in the transaction using hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, transactions

My requirement is - based on the value of a flag(say for eg. skipDbUpdate) in properties file, I want to save/update the entities or skip these entities in the ongoing transaction.
I have implemented a listener on the entity which will throw an exception if this flag is true, but now I have to enhance this behaviour to not throw an error but skip the update of the entity. I tried the below options :

1. @Immmutable annotation on the entity - Im not able to make this flag based, application uses using spring but I'm not able to combine @ConditionalOnProperty annotation with @Entity and @Immutatble annotations.

`@Entity @Immutatble public class EntityA {}`

2. using updateable=false, insertable=false on each field of the entity inside @Column annotation - again, Im not able to make this flag based (same reason as above).

   `@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)`
3. Calling entityManager.detach(o) method inside the Listener when flag is true, as suggested in this question - [How to make an Entity read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115527/how-to-make-an-entity-read-only)
   But this is trying to save the entities from other transaction and throwing the error - "
   `java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection:`"

As this is old code base which uses spring only, I cannot use annotations that easily.

Please suggest which is the best possible way to fulfill this requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you are using CRUDRepository you can extend the interface and override the save method & in this method you can check foe the flag if skipDb then do nothing else call super.save(….)

Comment: This approach lets me handle the cases where the save() or saveOrUpdate() method is called but when this entity is used in other entities via a Cascading relation, it saves them as is. This is the issue now.

Comment: In that case if possible remove the cascading and handle it in the service method by calling save/update separately

Comment: Those entitees are used across the project in multiple places, so it would be huge change. That is why I'm looking for options where I can manage it at the entity level only.