# Error with org.hibernate.MappingException

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm having a problem when i want to run my spring mvc. This is model to insert users by names and roles into the database

[image: My database image]

So, after getting the entity from database i have those files
App_User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user", schema = "spring")
public class AppUser {
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String telefone;
    private String tipo;
    private byte estado;
    private byte coordenador;
    private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "nome")
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "telefone")
    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "tipo")
    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "estado")
    public byte getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(byte estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "coordenador")
    public byte getCoordenador() {
        return coordenador;
    }

    public void setCoordenador(byte coordenador) {
        this.coordenador = coordenador;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "APP_USER_USER_PROFILE", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_ID",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<UserProfile> getUserProfiles() {
        return userProfiles;
    }

    public void setUserProfiles(Set<UserProfile> userProfiles) {
        this.userProfiles = userProfiles;
    }


}
```

The User_profile

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_profile")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="TYPE", length=15, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String type = UserProfileType.USER.getUserProfileType();

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    private Set<AppUser> userProfiles;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userProfiles")
    public Set<AppUser> getUserProfiles() {
        return userProfiles;
    }

    public void setUserProfiles(Set<AppUser> userProfiles) {
        this.userProfiles = userProfiles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserProfile [id=" + id + ", type=" + type + "]";
    }

}
```

When i run the tomcat server i getting this error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: user_profile, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(userProfiles)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:349)
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:322)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1360)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1851)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added annotation on method level:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userProfiles")
    public Set<AppUser> getUserProfiles() {
        return userProfiles;
    }
```

Move the annotation to your field:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userProfiles")
private Set<AppUser> userProfiles;
```

Either you have to select field level annotations or method level.

Refer to this post for more details: [Hibernate/JPA - annotating bean methods vs fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942035/hibernate-jpa-annotating-bean-methods-vs-fields)

> if you annotate the fields, Hibernate will use field access to set
>   and get those fields. If you annotate the methods, hibernate will use
>   getters and setters. Hibernate will pick the access method based on
>   the location of the @Id annotation and to my knowledge you cannot mix
>   and match. If you annotate a field with @Id, annotations on methods
>   will be ignored and visa versa.