# Hibernate one-to-one: getId() without fetching entire object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to fetch the id of a one-to-one relationship without loading the entire object.  I thought I could do this using lazy loading as follows:

```
class Foo { 
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Bar bar; 
}


Foo f = session.get(Foo.class, fooId);  // Hibernate fetches Foo 

f.getBar();  // Hibernate fetches full Bar object

f.getBar().getId();  // No further fetch, returns id
```

I want f.getBar() to *not* trigger another fetch.  I want hibernate to give me a proxy object that allows me to call .getId() without actually fetching the Bar object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same behaviour using 
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false) 

Single-valued associations are just not going well for me..

Comment: Its a Hibernate bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3718

See also comparing field or property access: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594597/hibernate-annotations-which-is-better-field-or-property-access

Comment: By default, the Proxy is not initialized when only the id is accessed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466913/how-to-avoid-initializing-a-hibernate-proxy-when-only-the-entity-id-is-needed

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use **property access strategy**

Instead of

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
private Bar bar;
```

Use

```
private Bar bar;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
public Bar getBar() {
    return this.bar;
}
```

Now it works fine!

A proxy is initialized if you call any method **that is not the identifier getter method**. But it just works when using property access strategy. Keep it in mind.

See: [Hibernate 5.2 user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#access)

Comment: Does that mean I have to change my entity to have all annotations at the property level for this to work? If i leave as is and move the one to one annotation to the property level and set access type to property it does not work

Comment: @shane lee See http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1955

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didnt trust the query being executed in my project so I added in my own db integration test to verify. I have it working now. The only change is to add access type on the id of the target entity. That was the only change needed.    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "FILECONTENT_ID_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "FILECONTENT_ID_SEQ",
        sequenceName = "FILECONTENT_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(
        name = "ID",
        nullable = false)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;

Comment: Is there any workaround to get at a field other than the identity/identifier getter method without full object retrieval/proxy initialization?

Comment: PatrickM, not using this feature. You could create a different reduced entity mapped to the same table.

Answer (score 33):

Just to add to the Arthur Ronald F D Garcia'post: you may force property access by `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` (or deprecated `@AccessType("property")`), see http://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/hibernate_lazy_field_access_annotations.shtml

Another solution may be:

```
public static Integer getIdDirect(Entity entity) {
    if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        LazyInitializer lazyInitializer = ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer();
        if (lazyInitializer.isUninitialized()) {
            return (Integer) lazyInitializer.getIdentifier();
        }
    }
    return entity.getId();
}
```

Works for detached entities, too.

Comment: I have used your idea, plus the fact that proxies cannot override final methods, to alter the `getId()` method itself to avoid initialization. Please, if you can, see my answer in this page and tell me what you think. I also don't understand why you are checking if `lazyInitializer.isUninitialized()`. Can't you always return `lazyInitializer.getIdentifier()` when the entity is a HibernateProxy?

Comment: I don't remember why I've used `if (lazyInitializer.isUninitialized())`. Maybe to use dirty trick only when really necessary. I think it may be omitted.

Comment: The Hibernate annotation "AccessType" is deprecated. Use the JPA2 annotation instead `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)`

Answer (score 29):

Unfortunately the accepted answer is wrong. Also other answers doesn't provide the simplest or a clear solution.

Use the Property Access Level for the `ID` of the `BAR` class.

```
@Entity
public class Bar {

    @Id
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

Just as simple as that :)

Comment: Doesn't work if ID is a composite key ( `@EmbeddedId` ) and logical names don't match column names ( eg. `@Column(name="U_NAME") private String username` ).

Comment: But how does it work, I've been reading @Access documentation, but I can't figure out how it impacts the behavior of the Hibernate proxy?

Comment: Property Based Access has many downfalls... please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594597/hibernate-annotations-which-is-better-field-or-property-access

Answer (score 17):

add **@AccessType("property")**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@AccessType("property")
protected Long id;
```

Comment: The Hibernate annotation "AccessType" is deprecated. Use the JPA2 annotation instead: `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)`

Answer (score 12):

The Java Persistence with Hibernate Book mentions this in "13.1.3 Understanding Proxies":

> As long as you access only the database identifier property, no
>   initialization of the proxy is necessary. (Note that this isn’t true
>   if you map the identifier property with direct field access; Hibernate
>   then doesn’t even know that the getId() method exists. If you call it,
>   the proxy has to be initialized.)

However, based on @xmedeko answer in this page I developed a hack to avoid initializing the proxy **even when using direct field access strategy**. Just alter the `getId()` method like shown below.

Instead of:

```
    public long getId() { return id; }
```

Use:

```
    public final long getId() {
        if (this instanceof HibernateProxy) {
            return (long)((HibernateProxy)this).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getIdentifier();
        }
        else { return id; }
    }
```

The idea here is to mark the `getId()` method as `final`, so that proxies cannot override it. Then, calling the method cannot run any proxy code, and thus cannot initialize the proxy. The method itself checks if its instance is a proxy, and in this case returns the id from the proxy. If the instance is the real object, it returns the id.

Comment: Haha this is really a horrible hack :) "Don't do it at home"

Comment: @OndraŽižka You are wrong. This code works perfectly. Also, it doesn't break any rules, there are no side effects, and it's clear what it's doing and why. So, if you can think of any reason not to use this code or why it is "horrible", please share.

Comment: It goes to Hibernate's internal classes which may change without prior notice. While I don't doubt it works perfectly, it's not something I would put into an  application that's supposed to last for years.

Comment: Wrong again. That's maybe the most fundamental piece of Hibernate functionality: To be able to get the proxy. This is also used to initialize the proxy, or remove the proxy, when necessary. It's used a lot both internally and in the application level. The chance of this going away without a complete Hibernate rewrite is virtually zero.

Comment: Sure, good for you. To others, I recommend not to rely on this unless they plan to stick with same major version.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

In org.hibernate.Session you have a function who do the work without lazy loading the entity :

public Serializable getIdentifier(Object object) throws HibernateException;

Found in hibernate 3.3.2.GA :

```
public Serializable getIdentifier(Object object) throws HibernateException {
        errorIfClosed();
        checkTransactionSynchStatus();
        if ( object instanceof HibernateProxy ) {
            LazyInitializer li = ( (HibernateProxy) object ).getHibernateLazyInitializer();
            if ( li.getSession() != this ) {
                throw new TransientObjectException( "The proxy was not associated with this session" );
            }
            return li.getIdentifier();
        }
        else {
            EntityEntry entry = persistenceContext.getEntry(object);
            if ( entry == null ) {
                throw new TransientObjectException( "The instance was not associated with this session" );
            }
            return entry.getId();
        }
  }
```

Comment: +1. It just doesn't work without Session, e.g. for detached entities.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a jackson hibernate datatype library here:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate

And you can configure the features:

```
 Hibernate4Module hibernate4Module = new Hibernate4Module();
 hibernate4Module.configure(Hibernate4Module.Feature.SERIALIZE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_LAZY_NOT_LOADED_OBJECTS, true);
```

This will include the id of the lazy loaded relationship-

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HQL query. The getBar() method will truly return a proxy, that won't be fetched until you invoke some data bound method. I'm not certain what exactly is your problem. Can you give us some more background?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What you describe is not what happens.  getBar() is causing the fetch to occur.  I would expect what you describe, that a proxy object is returned and no fetch is executed.  

Is there any other configuration I could be missing?

Comment: Actually the getId() following getBar() is causing the entity to be fetched. You're not missing any configuration IMO. Maybe some query like "select f.bar.id from Foo f where f.id=?" will do the trick for you.

Comment: The proxy object should not fetch the full Bar on bar.getId().  It already knows the id, since that is part of Foo. 

Anyway, it executes the fetch without invoking .getId()

Answer (score 0):

change your getter method like this:

```
public Bar getBar() {
    if (bar instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        HibernateProxy hibernateProxy = (HibernateProxy) this.bar;
        LazyInitializer lazyInitializer = hibernateProxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer();
        if (lazyInitializer.getSession() == null)
            bar = new Bar((long) lazyInitializer.getIdentifier());
    }

    return bar;
}
```