# JPA: Equality assertions with Proxy objects

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, junit, persistence

I have a class, User, which acts as the Persistence model for a table of Users in a database:

```js
public class User {
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Long userId;

@JoinColumn(name = "LAST_CHANGED_USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private User lastChangedUser;
...

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (userId != null ? userId.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof User)) {
        return false;
    }

    User other = (User) object;
    if ((this.userId == null && other.userId != null) || 
        (this.userId != null && !this.userId.equals(other.userId))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User[userId=" + userId + "]";
}
}
```

The field lastChangedUser is updated whenever changes are made to a User instance. Consider the following methods:

```js
private void setUsername(string username, User lastChangedUser){
    this.username = username;
    this.lastChangedUser = lastChangedUser;
}

public void updateUserName(Long userId, Long lastChangedUserId, String username){
    EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.getPersistenceManager()
       .getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

    User user = em.find(User.class, userId);
    User lastChangedUser = em.find(User.class, lastChangedUserId);

    transaction.begin();
    user.setUsername(username, lastChangedUser);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

and the unit test:

```js
public void testUpdateUsername(){
    UserFacade instance = new UserFacade();
    User john = instance.getUserByUserId(new Long(1));
    User jane = instance.getUserByUserId(new Long(2));

    // make the update and persist
    instance.updateUsername("JANE M. DOE", jane.userId, john.userId);

    // assert that john made the change to jane
    jane = instance.getUserByUserId(new Long(2));

    assertTrue(jane.username.equals("JANE M. DOE"));

    User actual = jane.lastChangedUser;
    User expected = john;

    // this assertion passes...
    assertTrue(actual.equals(expected));

    // yet this assertion fails!
    assertTrue(expected.equals(actual));

    // this fails as well.
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Using Netbeans 7.1.1, the test results screen returns the error message:

`FAILED: expected: User[id=1], but was: User[id=1].`

Upon inspection, the object `actual` is not of type `User`, but that of a Proxy object. I assume this is due to the LAZY fetch annotation. As such, the object's userid has a value of `null` and `expected.equals(actual)` returns `false`. Yet, `actual.equals(expected)` returns `true`. To add to my confusion, the failure message shows that `actual.userId` is not `null`, but equal to the expected id!

What quirk of Hibernate or JUnit is causing the actual User object to appear after failure?

Comment: For clarity, assume that the `setUsername` method is located in the `User` class.

Comment: Does `PersistenceManager.getPersistenceManager().getEntityManager();` always return the same entity manager in this scenario?  Entities from different instances of EntityManagers may not like each other.

Comment: I'm guessing you've overridden `equals()` on your entities.  What does your `equals()` method look like?

Comment: ɲeuroburɳ, the `getEntityManager()` method does not always return same instance of `EntityManager`. How does this factor into this scenario? Tim, the `equals` method is overriden; see the first code block for the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some friends and I figured out the solution thanks to [a question about obtaining ids without fetching the entire object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593722/hibernate-one-to-one-getid-without-fetching-entire-object). Since the object is a proxy, directly refrencing the field `userid` in `equals` yields a null value. However using the **getter method for the userid** results in fetching the actual value from the database. Hence, the `equals` method should look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object){
    if (!(object instanceof User)) {
        return false;
    }
    User other = (User) object;
    if ((this.getUserId() == null && other.getUserId() != null) || 
        (this.getUserId() != null && 
        !this.getUserId().equals(other.getUserId()))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and now the assertions will hold true.