# Hibernate/JPA - how to get id of a @ManyToOne field without triggering lazy load

Tags: hibernate, jpa

For example, there is an entity "User" with `@ManyToOne(fetch=Lazy)` field "Team". I have used `entityManager.find(User.class, userId)` get a user. At this point, if I call `user.getTeam()` a query will be send to database to get team object. Is there a way to get the team id without extra query?

Comment: Related question is more answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593722/hibernate-one-to-one-getid-without-fetching-entire-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For these purposes I do map the column twice. Once as many-to-one with `insert="true"` and `update="true"`.

then I append an **TeamId** property and mapp it as int `insert="false"` and `update="false"`. Instead of `column` mapping I use `formula`.

TeamId is then available after the first select.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we are currently using JPA annotations and trying to avoid using Hibernate specific feature. Do you know if I can use `@Column(updatable=false, insertable=false)` for this?

Comment: I would say this is it. check the Formula mapping as well, because we will use one column twice

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use Hibernate, add a @PostLoad method on you User entity, which will set  your teamId

1. Add a @Transient teamId property
2. Add a @PostLoad method :

Add a @PostLoad method

```
@PostLoad
    public void updateTeamIdInfos() {
        if (getTeam() != null) {
            setTeamId(getTeam().getId());
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this won't work for my very specific case. I was trying to avoid calling getTeam() function which will trigger lazy load