# Get primary key instead the whole object in OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "elements")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@XmlRootElement
public abstract class Elements implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idelement")
    private Integer idElement;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idElement")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<Alarms> alarmsCollection;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idElement")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<ElementsHistorical> elementsHistoricalCollection;   

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "elementsCollection")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<ElementsGroups> elementsGroupsCollection;


    //Constructors, getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "alarms")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Alarms")
public class Alarms implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idalarm")
    private Integer idAlarm;

    @JoinColumn(name = "idelement", referencedColumnName = "idelement")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Elements idElement;

    //Constructors, getters and setters

}
```

I created a jersey webservice and a DAO class with CRUD operations to treat `Alarms` data. With this implementation, when I call `GET` method, I get the whole `Elements` object inside the `Alarms` one. This is the DAO method called:

```
public List<Alarms> getAlarms(){
    Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();    
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Alarms");
    List<Alarms> alarms =  query.list();
    session.close();
    return alarms;
}
```

I don't want this `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` fetch type, as I just need the PK of `Elements`, but after some research this is the only way I found to make my service work.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311776/hibernate-foreign-keys-instead-of-entities) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593722/hibernate-one-to-one-getid-without-fetching-entire-object) approach, but I've not been able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left outer join fetch in you query.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Alarms alarm left outer join fetch alarm.idElement element");
```

Now you can keep fetch = FetchType.LAZY (which is default).

Comment: It didn't work, it returns the same result as before

Comment: FETCH is similar as EAGER, it's just another way to get data eager

Comment: Yeah but in this case you only get the associated objects when you need. Not everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @XmlTransient annotation to fields in Elements class that you want to ignore. 
like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "elements")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@XmlRootElement
public abstract class Elements implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idelement")
    private Integer idElement;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "code")
    @XmlTransient
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idElement")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @XmlTransient
    private Collection<Alarms> alarmsCollection;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idElement")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @XmlTransient
    private Collection<ElementsHistorical> elementsHistoricalCollection;   

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "elementsCollection")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @XmlTransient
    private Collection<ElementsGroups> elementsGroupsCollection;


    //Constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiselect with [Tuple](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html), for select only specific columns.

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
    Root<Alarms> root = cq.from(Alarms.class);
    CollectionJoin<Object, Object> joinCollection = root.joinCollection("alarmsCollection");
    cq.multiselect(joinCollection.get("idElement"));
    List<Tuple> tupleResult = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    for (Tuple t : tupleResult) {
        Long idElement = (Long) t.get(0);
    }
```