# @ManyToOne failed to lazy load when Hibernate second cache is enabled

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, lazy-loading, many-to-one

I have created two really simple entities in my project:

```
@Entity
@Access(FIELD)
public class TestA implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    @Version
    private Long hVersion;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    private TestB testB;

    // ...
}


@Entity
@Access(FIELD)
public class TestB implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    @Version
    private Long hVersion;

    // ...
}
```

We've got an optional `@ManyToOne` relation from TestA to TestB.

When I'm trying to fetch a TestA instance, like this:

```
entityManager.find(TestA.class, myId);
```

I'm getting two select: one for TestA, but also one for TestB, as it's eagerly loaded, which shouldn't happen.

```
Hibernate: select testa0_.id as id1_20_0_, testa0_.h_version as h_versio2_20_0_, testa0_.test_b_id as test_b_i3_20_0_ from test_a testa0_ where testa0_.id=?
Hibernate: select testb0_.id as id1_21_0_, testb0_.h_version as h_versio2_21_0_ from test_b testb0_ where testb0_.id=?
```

I tried all this combinations, even setting the relation as non-optional for the sake of testing:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
private TestB testB;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private TestB testB;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)
private TestB testB;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
private TestB testB;
```

That doesn't change anything, TestB is still eagerly loaded.

However, when I'm disabling the second level cache in `persistence.xml`, like this:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.debug" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
</properties>
```

Now TestB is lazy loaded, and I see the second select query only when I'm accessing TestA.getTestB().

When I'm looking at the logs, I can see that, with second level cache enabled, Hibernate resolve testB to put it in cache:

```
DEBUG [org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl] (default task-4) Hibernate RegisteredSynchronization successfully registered with JTA platform
DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (default task-4) select testa0_.id as id1_20_0_, testa0_.h_version as h_versio2_20_0_, testa0_.test_b_id as test_b_i3_20_0_ from test_a testa0_ where testa0_.id=?
DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl] (default task-4) Starting ResultSet row #0
DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl] (default task-4) On call to EntityIdentifierReaderImpl#resolve, EntityKey was already known; should only happen on root returns with an optional identifier specified
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (default task-4) Resolving associations for [com.monde3.lpt.veriqualis.model.test.TestA#00000000-9999-1111-1111-000000000001]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (default task-4) Adding entity to second-level cache: [com.monde3.lpt.veriqualis.model.test.TestA#00000000-9999-1111-1111-000000000001]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl] (default task-4) Initializing proxy: [com.monde3.lpt.veriqualis.model.test.TestB#00000000-9999-1111-1111-000000000002]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (default task-4) select testb0_.id as id1_21_0_, testb0_.h_version as h_versio2_21_0_ from test_b testb0_ where testb0_.id=?
DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl] (default task-4) Starting ResultSet row #0
DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl] (default task-4) On call to EntityIdentifierReaderImpl#resolve, EntityKey was already known; should only happen on root returns with an optional identifier specified
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (default task-4) Resolving associations for [com.monde3.lpt.veriqualis.model.test.TestB#00000000-9999-1111-1111-000000000002]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (default task-4) Adding entity to second-level cache: [com.monde3.lpt.veriqualis.model.test.TestB#00000000-9999-1111-1111-000000000002]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad] (default task-4) Done materializing entity [com.monde3.lpt.veriqualis.model.test.TestB#00000000-9999-1111-1111-000000000002]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl] (default task-4) Skipping aggressive release due to registered resources
DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader] (default task-4) Done entity load : com.monde3.lpt.veriqualis.model.test.TestB#00000000-9999-1111-1111-000000000002
```

I'm absolutely helpless here, as I cannot explain this behavior. Is there a mistake or a bad practice somewhere in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!

To be fully JPA compliant, a proxy should be initialized when any of its fields is accessed, *even the identifier* (which was not the case with Hibernate, to avoid a query loop).

Since [Hibernate 5.2.13](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12034), there is a new option to fulfill this rule, [`hibernate.jpa.compliance.proxy`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-jpa-compliance), which is set by default to `false` in order to keep consistency with Hibernate previous behaviors.

But! Since [Wildfly 14](https://docs.wildfly.org/14/Developer_Guide.html#hibernate-properties), this option is set by default to `true` in the server context. My code is running on a WF18 instance, so it's the same.

The solution was, like stated in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466913), to override the property in `persistence.xml`, resetting it to its default value, `false`:

```
<property name="hibernate.jpa.compliance.proxy" value="false" />
```