# How to add a JPA relationship to a subset list of attributes of a persisted Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Having the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  private UUID id;

  @NotBlank
  private String firstName;

  @NotBlank
  private String lastName;

  private Gender gender;
  private Instant birthDate;
  private String email;
  private String corporateEmail;

  @Embedded
  private Address address;

  // and many more 
  // + all getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Discipline {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  private UUID id;

  @NotNull
  private Instant date;
  private String infraction;
}
```

A `Discipline` is for a specific `Employee`. An `Employee` may have 0 to several disciplines. A discipline is for only one `Employee`, no more no less. In the `Discipline` world (micro-service), it requires only a few attributes from the full `Employee` class (id, firstName and lastName). In the `Employee` World (micro-service), all `Employee` fields are relevant.

How do I properly set my relation between both entities without fetching the `Employee` entity for each `Discipline` but only the required fields as I would do with a projection?

Must I refactor my `Employee` entity by extracting a superclass with only the attributes' subset?

In a magical world, I would like to have `Discipline` entity defines as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Discipline {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  private UUID id;

  @NotNull
  private Instant date;
  private String infraction;

  @ManyToOne
  private EmployeeProfile employeeProfile;
}

public interface EmployeeProfile {

  UUID getId();
  String getFirstName();
  String getLastName();
}
```

Where `EmployeeProfile` here should look similar to what a Spring Data JPA interface based projection would use.

Aimed goals by doing this:

- Avoid incoming issues when our entities will be versionned. In fact, we don't want an `addDiscipline` request to fail due to an outdated employee instance on an irrelevant attribute. This could happen if we link `Discipline` to the full `Employee
- Improve performance by reducing load to our DB (slimmer entities the better)
- Reduce coupling between our entities as much as possible.
- Keep entities and DB design as simple as possible.

Comment: If exposing the domain model directly via a REST API doesn't work for you then use the DTO pattern. https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

Comment: How about a separate `@Immutable EmployeeProfile` entity, mapped to the `EMPLOYEE` table?

Comment: @crizzis If I understand properly, you're suggesting on using a one-to-one association using shared primary keys linking both `Employee` and `EmployeeProfile` entities correct? If so, would it not result in two DB tables?

Comment: I'm suggesting to create another entity mapped to the same `EMPLOYEE` table, but with only a subset of the columns mapped onto entity fields

Comment: @AlanHay it was my first natural solution to this problem but, to do so, my Discipline entity would only have the employee id (linked properly with JPA which I don't know yet how) as `@ManyToOne(...) private UUID employeeId;`. This solution was challenged by stating it's not really JPA compliant having an entity persisted with only the id of another entity. 

I could still make it work by using property access strategy as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2598301 since getting the identifier won't trigger a full fetch from DB. But it's kind of odd.

Comment: @crizzis Ok I think I get what you meant. It would be as 
`@Entity @Table("Employee") public class Employee {}` with `@Entity @Table("Employee") public class EmployeeProfile {}` where the latter one has only a subset of all the `Employee` attributes. Correct?

Comment: Yup. As I mentioned, you might also want `@Immutable` to prevent accidental modifications

Comment: Feeling dumb asking this but which `@Immutable` you're refering too? `org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable`, `javax.annotation.concurrent.Immutable`, `org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.stereotypes.Immutable` or `org.springframework.data.annotation.Immutable`? And this is only to prevent modifications to this entity since anyway default cascade operation is "do nothing", correct?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @crizzis who proposed what I was looking for. Here's the solution if anybody else is looking for this in future.

SOLUTION:
Simply have two entities, one with all the attributes and another one with only the subset you're interested in and have both entities using same table as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  private UUID id;

  @NotBlank
  private String firstName;

  @NotBlank
  private String lastName;

  private Gender gender;
  private Instant birthDate;
  private String email;
  private String corporateEmail;

  @Embedded
  private Address address;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@Immutable
public class EmployeeProfile {

  @Id
  private UUID id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
}
```

Than you can have link other entities on this `EmployeeProfile` class as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Discipline {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  private UUID id;

  @NotNull
  private Instant date;
  private String infraction;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
  private EmployeeProfile employeeProfile;
}
```

As by default on `ManyToOne`relationship no operations are cascaded, this suits perfectly our needs.

@AlanHay proposed to go down the REST way by having a REST endpoint returning this specific DTO. It is another great solution especially in a micro-service architecture.

As in our case, all our entities are still persisted in the same DB, we are going with the above solution as first step of doing micro-services is to build a great/decoupled monolithic application and because it will handle everything in only one DB query. And when the day come to split `Discipline` and `Employee` in different micro-services, it will be very simple to do so as Discipline table hold only the employee id, avoiding painful DB migration.