# Query value of JoinColumn with JPQL

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have two JPA entities

```
public class Job {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "service")
  public Service service;

  @Column(name = "queue_time")
  public Long queueTime;

  @Column(name = "run_time")
  public Long runTime;
}

public class Service {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  public Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  public String name;

  @Column(name = "host")
  public String host;
}
```

Now I want to do some aggregation queries with JPQL:

```
SELECT job.service.id, AVG(job.queueTime), AVG(job.runTime) FROM Job job GROUP BY job.service.id
```

The resulting SQL query (I'm using a MySQL database) looks like this:

```
SELECT t0.id, AVG(t1.queueTime), AVG(t1.runTime) FROM Service t0, Job t1 WHERE (t0.service = t1.id) GROUP BY t0.id
```

As you can see, JPA translates my JPQL query to a SQL query with a join. This however slows down the query dramatically. The following SQL query executes ~6 time faster and returns the exact same result set:

```
SELECT t1.service, AVG(t1.queueTime), AVG(t1.runTime) FROM Job t1 GROUP BY t1.service
```

If I change the JPQL query to

```
SELECT job.service, AVG(job.queueTime), AVG(job.runTime) FROM Job job GROUP BY job.service
```

the resulting SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.name, t0.host AVG(t1.queueTime), AVG(t1.runTime) FROM Service t0, Job t1 WHERE (t0.service = t1.id) GROUP BY t0.id, t0.name, t0.host
```

Is there a way to write the JPQL which *only* queries the job table without making a join to the service table?

Comment: If you care about performance, why not use NativeQuery?

Comment: Because the software has to run on multiple DBMS like Postgres, MySQL, DB2 & MS SQL Server

Comment: You are not using any vendor specific sql extensions as far as I see. Why it should be a problem?

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I should give it a try :-) But I'd be interested in answers related to JPQL anyway.

Comment: Native SQL is one option, adding a basic mapping in Job for the foreign key so it can be used in JPQL queries is another.  EclipseLink also allows creating a query key on the foreign key, so it can also be used in queries just like a mapping would.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Keys

Answer (score 0):

This question solved the issue for me: [How can I retrieve the foreign key from a JPA ManyToOne mapping without hitting the target table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941797/how-can-i-retrieve-the-foreign-key-from-a-jpa-manytoone-mapping-without-hitting)

I took the second solution (b) Use read-only fields for the FKs)