# JPA + Hibernate - How to get FK of child entity without fetching that entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

A possible answer to my question is located here:
[How can I retrieve the foreign key from a JPA ManyToOne mapping without hitting the target table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941797/how-can-i-retrieve-the-foreign-key-from-a-jpa-manytoone-mapping-without-hitting)

However, the preferable solution (property access) does not work in my case (I got missing column exception - why?)

The model looks like this: Entities `Parent` and `Child`. Table `parent` has column `child_id` which is `PK` of `child` table so it is typical `@ManyToOne` relation.

Now the point is, if I fetch `Parent` entities, I need to have access to `FK` value (aka. `PK` of `Child` entity) without fetching `Child` entities. How can I do that?

I use `Annotations` and my mapping looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent extends AbstractEntity {

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "patent_id", nullable = true)
private Child child;

@Column(name="child_id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
private Integer childId;

public Child getChild() {
    return patent;
}

public void setChild(Child child) {
    this.child = child;
}


public Integer getChildId(){
    return childId;
}
}
```

And what I want to do is call `parent.getChild().getId()` without extra fetches of `Child` entity from DB.

According to the answer I have mentioned above, If I moved annotations from field to getter (in `Parent` entity am I right?), requested behavior would be out of the box. However, when I move annotations to getter, I get a validation exception that `child` column is missing (curious, why `child` not `child_id` as declared?)

**PS:** Shown workaround to declare a `FK` column as separate field works fine, but I don't think that this is the way it should be done.

Comment: I think when you do a lazy load hibernate do not even fetch that column. So if you want that to appear without fetching you should use native query.

Comment: Not an option, I use `Criteria API`

Comment: Try @Formula annotation and type out what you want. might work. Not tested

Comment: @dinesh707 this is not JPA annotation

Comment: org.hibernate.annotations.Formula; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986318/calculated-property-with-jpa-hibernate

Comment: @dinesh Please stick to JPA standard. Its not `JPA` annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after reading following article http://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/hibernate_lazy_field_access_annotations.shtml
I have realized, that property access should be to the property I want to fetch, not the actual `child` object. So changing `id` access of `AbstractEntity`from field to property, makes the trick.