# "SELECT *" into a hibernate entity, without populating any relationships / join table data

Tags: java, hibernate-4.x

I'm looking to load data into a hibernate entity by running something like `select * from <table> where id = ?`. I'm only interested in the data sitting in `<table>` -- *no* joins whatsoever.

I can achieve this by using the following:

```
T result = (T) getSession()
            .createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + idColumn + " = ?")
            .setInteger(0, id)
            .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(type))
            .uniqueResult();
```

But this only works for entities that don't have relationships. For any entity with a relationship to another, i get a `PropertyNotFoundException` when the result transformer is trying to set some `<relationshipName>_id` property on my entity (eg. `org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for administration_id on class com.xxxxxx.xxxx.model.AdministrationPIN`

Are there any other transformers that could automatically handle this. Or possibly some sort of object binder that could be used from an entity map, if I was to use the `Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP` result transformer instead?

**Update**
It's important that *all* of the data sitting in the table is loaded into the entity, *including* the relationship data. So if entity `A` has a OneToOne with entity `B`, and I load entity `A` using this method, `a.getB()` should return an instance of `B`, but the `B` instance should *only* be populated with its identifier.

Comment: It looks like simple query, cant you just use HQL insteed of native SQL? As for your update, I don't think it is possible. However maybe this could help you a little bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885310/jpa-hibernate-how-to-get-fk-of-child-entity-without-fetching-that-entity

Comment: Would using HQL prevent table joins?

Comment: It depends on what kind of `FETCH` policy you have delcared. If it is always `LAZY` than yes, no joins nor aditional selects will be performed.

Comment: Indeed, but I would like this to function irrespective of the ``FETCH`` policy - for example, OneToOne relationships take special configuration to be set as ``LAZY``

Comment: It sould be the other way around. All of your associations should be set to `LAZY` fetching and they should be fetched when needed with `FETCH` mode of the query. There is no way to disable `EAGAR` fetching declared im mapping files or annotations (I haven't heard of such)

Comment: I disagree that all associations should be set to ``LAZY`` - that is a more application-specific configuration, which does not suit my needs.

Comment: You cannot disagree that if it would be lazy, than it would be more flexible, as you could always force H to fetch lazy associations eagarly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62168/discussion-between-jlb-and-antoniossss).