# Ebean with unidirectional OneToMany relationship causing duplicate column exception during insert

Tags: ebean

I have a table ENTRY with unique id UID. A second table PROGRAM with ID column as the key and PROGRAM_LIST_UID foreign key that refers to UID in ENTRY. I did not create the names, this is legacy code I am trying to maintain.

```java
@Entity(name="entry")
public class Entry {
    @Id
    public int uid;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="program_list_uid", referencedColumnName="uid")
    public List<Program> programList;

    ...
}

@Entity(name="program")
public class Program {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    @Column(length=150,name="program_name")
    public String programName;

    @Column(name="program_list_uid")
    public Integer entryId = 0;
}
```

When trying to save entry `Ebean.save(entry)`, I get an exception

> ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[[SQL0121] Duplicate name PROGRAM_LIST_UID not allowed...

Trace shows that the insert statement indeed has the `program_list_uid` specified twice:

```sql
insert into program (program_list_uid, program_name, program_list_uid) 
values (?,?,?)
```

The only way I have found to make this work is to remove the `entryId` from `Program`. However this property is used elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for cleaning up my question. Is there a reason for removing the syntax highlighting?

Comment: No - not at all - SO should *normally* do the syntax highlighting automatically - doesn't work here, it seems, sorry for that. Added back the "hints" for the SO renderer - hope it works again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turns out to be adding `insertable = false, updatable = false` to `@Column` annotation on `entryId`. [How can I retrieve the foreign key from a JPA ManyToOne mapping without hitting the target table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17061897/1373031)

```java
@Entity(name="program")
public class Program {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    @Column(length=150,name="program_name")
    public String programName;

    @Column(name="program_list_uid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Integer entryId = 0;
}
```