# Why @Transient of ejb3 is not working as expected? It still gets persisted

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, ejb-3.0, transient

```
import javax.persistence.*;

simple POJO
class A {

@Transient
protected transient someClass X;

}
```

Despite this, in the database, I still see it persisted?
Any idea of this weird behavior?

Comment: you sure using javax.persistence.Transient ?

Comment: yeah.. javax.persistence.Transient   \n  Howeever I haven't adde @transient to getter/setter methods...

Comment: Ooh my goodness, it needs to be added at getter/setters also/...

Comment: no it doesn't :) You should annotate ether the fields `or` the accessors.

Comment: I dont see the entity annotation is part of embedded object ?

Comment: A is and Entity or Embeddable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you mixed annotating both fields and getters. According to the JPA spec, you must remain consistent, in which you JPA annotate either only the fields, or only the getters. (usually JPA looks at the ID field and than decides to consider the fields or getters).

Comment: Initially i had added annotaion only for field. It didnt work . If you see I have also made filed java transient.   But it didnt work. When I added to getter/setters it worked..(i.e not got persisted.).Do you think getter/setters are more important than field for transient annotaion??

Comment: See these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188048/why-should-anybody-put-annotations-on-the-getters-or-setters-when-using-jpa-to-m http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594597/hibernate-annotations-which-is-better-field-or-property-access http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942035/hibernate-jpa-annotating-bean-methods-vs-fields

Comment: Yes its solved..thanks. I am not sure of how to close it