# Spring Data JPA select sequence for different bases, and set value to entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sequence

I need implement next logic:

I have entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GUID")
    private String guid;

    @Column(name = "MESSAGE_ID")
    private String messageId;

    @Column(name = "SOME_VALUE")
    private String someValue;
```

And I need set to `someValue` generated value consisting of

`"some prefix"+sequencefrom DB + "some suffix";`

I can make select `sequense from Db`, generate `vsomeValue` and set it to entity, but maby Is there a way to make it easier? Because in my version I use two bases, and I have to write two native query for select a sequence and use the appropriate one depending on the profile.

I need somthig like this:

```
    @Column(name = "SOME_VALUE")
    @Value(MyGenerator.class)
    private String someValue;
```

and in `MyGenerator.class` implement logic for generate `someValue` from prefix, sequence and suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of annotating the class members, annotate the getters and setters, and put your logic there.

Further reference in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188048/why-should-anybody-put-annotations-on-the-getters-or-setters-when-using-jpa-to-m).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for ***Custom Sequence based ID generator***.

[This](https://thoughts-on-java.org/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/) is a nice article on it which might help you.