# How to update jpa entity without setters

Tags: jpa

I would like to design my JPA entities without setters (using annotated fields), because i love "immutable" objects.

All entities will get hashCode/equal implementation without using the generated id (i read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033905/create-the-perfect-jpa-entity)).

My problem is how to update such an entity in data base? Is this possible or is the immutability either on both sided (object and entity) or on no side?

Comment: how would you update the fields of such an entity in Java ?

Comment: never i just would create a new object, i only need a way to tell entitymanager that it should update an entity with the data of an object, my hope is there is some thing like update(id,object)

Comment: No there isn't. The API is public http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html   persist and merge are the methods for persisting/updating

Comment: i think merge could do what i want - couldn't it? How does merge decide if it should persist a new entity or update an existent entity - by @Id or by equals?

Comment: @dermoritz did you solve it? I also love immutable objects and coding in DDD so I have same problem now :D