# Could not set field value by reflection error

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have a class like below:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.framework.model.core.baseInfo.SubSystemType;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "CORE_POWER_TYPE_DOCUMENT")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "Base_Power_Type_Id")
@Getter
@Setter
public class StoragePowerType extends BasePowerType {

    @Override
    public SubSystemType getsystemType() {
        return SubSystemType.storing;
    }

}
```

and below exception id throwed:

"****counld not set field value [org.model.core.power.type.StoragePowerType@203cb33d] value by reflection ****"

Do you know what is the problem??

Comment: Provide code and exceptions as text in code and quotes, please.

Comment: i put text in question

Answer (score 0):

Most likely some property inside `BasePowerType` is declared as `private`, with no getter and setter.

Each property of JPA entity must either be `public` or have methods `get<PropertyName>()` and `set<PropertyName>()` defined. Otherwise the framework you are using (Hibernate?) will not be able to access the property.
So use either:

```java
public Long id;
```

Or:

```java
private Long id;

public Long getId() { return id; }
public void setId(Long value) { id = value; }
```

Try to follow guidelines from [here: Create the perfect JPA entity [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033905/create-the-perfect-jpa-entity)
.

Comment: i dont have any property in basePowerType class! only i Override a public class that define in its root class.