# Hibernate annotation location in java file

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I am following hibernate tutorial from the "Beginning hibernate" book.
And I see that the annotations like @Id, @Column are specified above the getXXX() methods.

such as:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public long getId()
{
    return id;
}

@Column(unique=true)
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

But not in the attribute definition it self like:

```
private long id;
private String name;
```

Is there a link/reference that specifies where the annotation should be placed? and the reasoning behind it.
More specifically; how does Hibernate interpret the placement of different annotations and is there a guide to it?

I am talking about the javax.persistence.* annotations

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
```

I have looked at 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single

I am using:

```
Hibernate 4.2.6.Final 
Windows 8, 32 bit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations can be placed on fields or on methods. The option you choose is really a matter of personal preference although I have seen it said to prefer fields over methods.

Personally I prefer field annotations as I find them much easier to work with:

- all the persistence mappings are located at the top of your source
  file.
- if you have any any other methods in your Entity not    concerned
  with JPA mappings then these have to be annotated with    @Transient
  which 'just seems wrong'.
- when using property access you    will    have to include a getter
  even if you don't require one (although       this can be be private
  (or at least protected).
- if you want to encapsulte add/remove operations for assocations then
  it is often desirable to return a wrapped, Unmodifiable collection:
  you cannot do this if the persistance mappings are on the property.

When scanning your class Hibernate will firstly look for a field or method with the @Id annotation and will then look for other mappings accordingly, viz. if @Id is on a field only other fields will be scanned: any mappings defined on a method will, by default, be ignored and vice versa although this behaviour can be modified using:

```
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
```

[What is the purpose of AccessType.FIELD, AccessType.PROPERTY and @Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874528/what-is-the-purpose-of-accesstype-field-accesstype-property-and-access)