# SpringDataJPA persist: only populate a field when querying, but not save

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am using SpringDataJpa. Let's say I have an entity called `USER` (with properties first, last and level). Which annotation should I use on the level property, so it's only populated when querying, but not ignored during saving the object to database?
I have tried `@Transient`, but then the field is ignored when querying...

Comment: It would help if you provide your entity code. So we know how your mapping currently is set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following.

**First** make sure that you **use JPA Field Access** - so your JPA provider is not relying on getters and setters. If your `@Id` annotation is set on the field and not the getter you should be fine. See the accepted answer of this question for more details on the JPA access type:

[What is the purpose of AccessType.FIELD, AccessType.PROPERTY and @Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874528/what-is-the-purpose-of-accesstype-field-accesstype-property-and-access)

**Additionally you do not provide a setter for your `level` property**. So the field can just be read by the caller.

Further more you can **express that the field cannot be written** using the `@Column` annotation on the level property.

```
@Column(name = "LEVEL", updatable = false, insertable = false)
```