# JPA: difference between setting @Id on fied and on getter

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I use EclipseLink and I get very strange results. Please, consider the following code:

This code works:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "someTable")
public class SomeClass{
    @Id// PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column (name = "somecol")// PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This code also works:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "someTable")
public class SomeClass{
    @Id// PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //@Column (name = "somecol")// PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This code also works:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "someTable")
public class SomeClass{

    private String id;

    @Id// PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //@Column (name = "somecol")// PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This code DOESN'T work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "someTable")
public class SomeClass{

    private String id;

    @Id // PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column (name = "somecol")// PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception Description: Entity class [class SomeClass] has no primary key specified. It should define either an @Id, @EmbeddedId or an @IdClass. If you have defined PK using any of these annotations then make sure that you do not have mixed access-type (both fields and properties annotated) in your entity class hierarchy.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.noPrimaryKeyAnnotationsFound(ValidationException.java:1425)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.validatePrimaryKey(EntityAccessor.java:1542)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processMappingAccessors(EntityAccessor.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.process(EntityAccessor.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage2(MetadataProject.java:1808)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1948)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.jpa.ProviderWrapper.createEntityManagerFactory(ProviderWrapper.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.jpa.proxy.EMFServiceProxyHandler.createEMF(EMFServiceProxyHandler.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.jpa.proxy.EMFServiceProxyHandler.syncGetEMFAndSetIfAbsent(EMFServiceProxyHandler.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.jpa.proxy.EMFServiceProxyHandler.invoke(EMFServiceProxyHandler.java:73)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
```

Why doesn't last code work? How to explain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because there is something like `@Access` which you must specify on a entity and field level if you would like to use the mixed mode. There are two values `AccessType.PROPERTY` and `AccesType.FIELD`.

<s>The default access type is defined by where you put your identifier annotation (`@Id`). If you put it on the field - it will be `AccessType.FIELD`, if you put it on the getter - it will be `AccessType.PROPERTY`.</s> - edited, not defined by JPA.

If you want to annotate not fields but properties (still having @Id on field) you must define a getter and annotate it as `AccessType.PROPERTY`. (or vice versa for `@Id` on getter).

Comment: I am confused: If the place `@Id` is placed decide the `AccessType`, why would it complain for "has no primary key specified"?  Base on your answer, the last example will default to `AccessType.PROPERTY` and the `@Id` annotation is putting at the correct place isn't it?

Comment: just a further search give me this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13874900/395202  What you said is the same as the **answer** but it turned out, in the **comment** section of the answer, suggested such behavior (`@Id` decides `AccessType`) is not JPA standard. (And it doesn't explain the behavior OP is facing too)

Comment: I've just read what you posted. Honestly I remember that about AccessType - simply because I have a exercise about it on my JPA training (but I use Hibernate as the provider). What I understood right now is that EclipseLink treats it differently. Nevertheless, you're right. My answer didn't answer the actual question, which was why there's no-PK-exception :). But for sure helped to avoid the symptoms.

Comment: I guess JPA's standard insist the access type need to be standard through out the class (even in the whole hierarchy I believe).  It is vendor's choice to decide how to deal with cases of inconsistency.  Good answer though as it give the correct direction for other (incl me) to find out more for the problem :)