# All my fields have a prefix. How can I tell that to hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

E.g. I have:

```
  @Column(name = "username")
  private String m_username;
```

Note that the @Column annotation only affects the database column name.

Hibernate still thinks the name of the property is 'm_username'.

How can I tell Hibernate that the property name is just 'username'?

Please tell me there is a way to do this...

Edit: I removed the @AccessType annotation in my code example, as it is not relevant for this question.

Update: After switching everything to field access, this exception happens:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: username of: mypackage.model.User
```

It happens here:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
User result = (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

And the reason is most likely that hibernate only 'knows' of a property called 'm_username', while I think of it and program against a property named 'username'. Also note that my getters/setters are called: "getUsername()" and "setUsername(String value)" (automatically generated).

Answer (score 0):

why do you use `AccessType.PROPERTY`?

remove it and it is accessed by 'field'.

do not mix field and property annotations. stick to one or the other.

Comment: That's because I want access type property, but prefer to specify the annotations on the fields. The getters/setter are generated automatically (see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915606/how-can-i-place-the-hibernate-annotations-on-the-fields-but-always-have-propert).

Comment: @Zalumon why can't you use field access? It solves a couple of issues, eg. with getter/setter side-effects. It would solve your problem too. All in all persisting an object is about persisting its *internal* state.

Comment: @Adam: Actually I just switched everything to field access to see if I could get it to work that way, but I'm still having problems. I'll update the question with the exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge we can't* .

There is still one issue with the way `hibernate` looks up the methods 
for a `given property name`.

Suppose you have a `property` with a name like "mProperty" (first 
lowercase, second uppercase, rest doesn't matter). Not the `accessor` 
methods in the source code will be `getMProperty` and `setMProperty`.

The way `BasicPropertyAccessor.getterMethod` is implemented in that way .

Comment: Really no way? I can't be the only one with this requirement. And I don't understand what you're trying to say with the "mProperty" example. In my case it would be defined as m_mProperty, and the accessor methods would be named getMProperty/setMProperty, as you said (which seems correct to me).

Comment: I mentioned :As per my knowledge::  And in my mProperty example i am just telling how BasicPropertyAccessor will fetch for a geter method .

Comment: I think I understand now what you were trying to tell me. And I found some forum thread somewhere that suggests subclassing the BasicPropertyAccessor (see my own answer to this question).

Comment: check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313095/jpa-hibernate-and-custom-table-prefixes

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to be related to database table/column names, that problem is already solved by the @Column annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I found one lead here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=943110

But the thread is 7 years old and I don't know how to apply this to annotation based configuration (I don't have an xml configuration file).