# Hibernate: setter and getter with different names as field

Tags: hibernate

Let's assume I have the String property `fullName` but I want to represent it as two separate strings as shown in the example below.

Is it possible to set up Hibernate so that it stores the full name in a single column and uses the accessor methods (`getFullName`, `setFullName`) to do that ?

The problem is that I do **not** want to declare - just to make Hibernate happy - an unnecessary String field `fullName` which will not be used because that would decrease the cleanness of the code.

```
String lastName;
String firstName;
public String getFullName() {
     return firstName+" "+lastName;
}
public void setFullName(String n) {
     firstName=extractFirstName(n);
     lastName=extractLastName(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could annotate the getFullname method to store it to a column in database.

Check this link:

[Hibernate Annotations - Which is better, field or property access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594597/hibernate-annotations-which-is-better-field-or-property-access)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transient` annotation to make Hibernate ignore methods as you like:

```
@Transient
public String getFullName() {
     return firstName+" "+lastName;
}

@Transient
public void setFullName(String n) {
     firstName=extractFirstName(n);
     lastName=extractLastName(n);
}
```

Comment: I would like Hibernate to store the fullName via those very methods.