# utspring JPA @Column (name="") name doesn`t work if annotation on field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

1. I have a table with `AlternateBillingEmail` column - historical
   issue
2. I have set up an `ImprovedNamingStrategy` in my annotation
   configuration - many tables are ok
3. I have added a `@Column(name="AlternateBillingEmail")` on a field in entity

Result - `@Column` ignored, I can see alternate_billing_email in hibernate logs, but If I put it on a getter method, it works? Why?

Comment: There are several posts for that (or similar) case, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594597/hibernate-annotations-which-is-better-field-or-property-access

Comment: "utspring" ? what? that aside, nobody sees your class so cannot know the context of your Column annotation

Comment: Show ur mapping on POJO to get proper solution. Add some code snippet to question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you need simple and convenient code, use annotation on a field, if you need more complicated logic,  use it on getter method. Spring recommends to use field method, but in practice I would use getter way.