# Hibernate load method

Tags: hibernate

I have a question regarding `load` method of Hibernate. 
from the below code fragments, the first one throws `ObjectNotFoundException` where as the second one, simply returns a proxy. what is the difference between annotating `@Id` at field level and annotating at getter method() level

1)

```
class Test {

  @Id
  private long id;

}
```

2)

```
class Test {

  private long id;

  @Id
  public long getId() {
      return id;
  }

}
```

Thank you all

regards
sivakiran B

Comment: in the second snippet it is "@Id" not "@id" . Sorry for the typo

Comment: I think this question has answers to your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594597/hibernate-annotations-which-is-better-field-or-property-access

Comment: Do you have getters in the first case?

Comment: @v.ladynev, yes we have getters also in the first case as well