# hibernate field inheritance without baseclass access

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I want to persist one class that extends another from an external API...

I've no access to API class so I can't anotate it as @MappedSuperclass or @Entity nor anotate its fields

But i would like to persit the public fields from superclass plus extra fields from my extended class.

```
//i've no access to modifications on this class as it comes from external api
public class BaseClass{

public int field1;
public int field2;
public int field3;

}

@Entity
public class MyClass extends BaseClass{

public int extraField1;
public int extraField2;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int extraField3;

}
```

How can I approach this situation?
I'm using Hibernate 5.1.0.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating getters/setters for the inherited fields and using accessor-based annotations (like is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/757330/79450))