# Hibernate annotations and foreign key relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a domain object annotated like this for hibernate support.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INPUT")
public class AppInput {

  /**
   * Unique id for this request
   */
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "INPUT_ID")
  private long requestId;
  /**
   * 
   */
  @Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
  private String emailId;
  /**
   * 
   */
  @Column(name = "REQUEST_DATE")
      private Date requestDate;
  /**
    * 
   */
  @Column(name = "INPUT_STATUS")
   private char status;
  /**
   * 
   */
   @Column(name = "EXPECTED_ORDER_DATE")
  private Date expectedOrdDt;

//Getter and setters
   }
```

The property emailId is a foreign key referring to say emailId column in User table. Lets say i add a property like this to AppInput.java
`private User userDetails;`
How do i annotate this so that, whenever i fetch AppInput from db, the corresponding user details also get populated?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> The property emailId is a foreign key referring to say emailId column in User table.

Then don't add the `emailId` property, add a `User`.

> (...) How do i annotate this so that, whenever i fetch AppInput from db, the corresponding user details also get populated?

Not sure since it could be a `ManyToOne` or `OneToOne` but I'll assume it's a `ManyToOne`:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="USERDETAILS_EMAIL_ID", referencedColumnName="EMAIL_ID")
private User userDetails;
```

The `fetch` annotation element is for demonstration purpose, `EAGER` being actually the default value. The `name` and `referencedColumn` annotation elements in  `JoinColumn` are also optional. Below a short summary from the JPA specification:

> #### 11.1.21 JoinColumn Annotation
>
> The `JoinColumn` annotation is used to
>   specify a column for joining an entity
>   association or element collection.
>
> Table 20 lists the annotation elements
>   that may be specified for the
>   `JoinColumn` annotation and their
>   default values.
>
> If the `JoinColumn` annotation itself
>   is defaulted, a single join column is
>   assumed and the default values
>   described in Table 20 apply.
>
> The `name` annotation element defines
>   the name of the foreign key column.
>   The remaining annotation elements
>   (other than `referencedColumnName`)
>   refer to this column and have the same
>   semantics as for the `Column`
>   annotation.
>
> If the
>   `referencedColumnName` element is
>   missing, the foreign key is assumed to
>   refer to the primary key of the
>   referenced table.

See the **Table 20** in the spec for complete and exhaustive details.

Comment: Yes it is a many to one. I tried the code and it says fetch is not a valid attribute.I tried removing it and it says "MappingException.Could not determine type for a.b.c.User"

Comment: @user378101: Little typo, `fetch` is an annotation element of `ManyToOne`. Regarding the second error, it seems `User` is not an entity (you need to annotate it with `@Entity` and to declare it in your `persistence.xml`). Only entities can be used in associations.

Comment: I suspected this but the User class is already annotated with @Entity.

Comment: @user378101: Can you show the `User` class? Are you sure you don't get any error message at application startup (something that would prevent `User` to get mapped properly)?

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I had annotated the getUser method. Tried annotating the field and it works. What is the difference?

Comment: @user378101: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286508/where-to-put-hibernate-annotations