# name attribute doesn't seem to work in Field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

As I am trying to map Entity to tables using JPA (Hibernate implementation) I found something confusing

when i use annotation on getter, things are OK

```
@Column(name = "main_battery_voltage", precision = 2)
public float getMainBatteryVoltage() {
    return mainBatteryVoltage;
}
```

but When I try the same thing on field, field name is used and attribute

```
@Column(name = "main_battery_voltage", precision = 2)
private float mainBatteryVoltage;
```

System ignores name attribute, runs with column name mainBatteryVoltage in DB and consequently failed task.

I am using MySQL and this is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="SolarPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.cs.solar.db.entity.User</class>
        <class>com.cs.solar.db.entity.Lamp</class>
        <class>com.cs.solar.db.entity.Project</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"     value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <!--<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SOLAR"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
     <persistence-unit name="TestSolar" />
</persistence>
```

Although it works now, I am curious what cause this problem, thank

Comment: Which Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: I am using Hibernate 4.0

Comment: Remove the name attribute, namings should take its defaults, it is camelCase to camel_case underscored. Also, make sure, the field access type is set. And try doing this not with a float, but with a string for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a short explanation here:
[Hibernate Annotation Placement Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305880/hibernate-annotation-placement-question)

The point is:
"the access type used by Hibernate will be field or property. The EJB3 spec requires that you declare annotations on the element type that will be accessed, i.e. **the getter method if you use property access, the field if you use field access**. Mixing EJB3 annotations in both fields and methods should be avoided. **Hibernate will guess the access type**..."