# What's different between field @ManyToOne and get @ManyToOne?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lombok

I Have Some Question that like title.

There is some Object with JPA (hibernate).

```
@Data
public class A {
    private String id;
    private String content;
    ...
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = B.class)
    private B b;
}

@Data
public class B {
    private String id;
    private String content;
}
```

But that code is occur error 'MappingException'.

if i change to class A like this,

```
@Data
public class A {
    private String id;
    private String content;
    ...
    private B b;
    ...

    // Other field is generated by lombok
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = B.class)
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

It works very clearly..
I don't understand different between this two way.
Anyone know about this situation?

Comment: Thanks for B_Osipiuk. that is exactly what i want.

Comment: In fact, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305880/hibernate-annotation-placement-question is more helpful for me